# Offline 3d map and functionalities such as simulation,3D map for routing, slope aspect, viewshed, object elevation control

Tags: .net, leaflet, cesiumjs

The objective is
•   Web based 3D solution that works on intranet
•   If background maps need to be created, we will test this (action)
•   How many functions we want to see on 3D web portal –
a)   view control,
b)   object elevation control,
c)   line of sight,
d)   viewshed,
e)   slope aspect,
f)   elevation profile,
g)   3D Map for viewing
h)   3D map for routing,
i)   simulation
•   With the below web portal links identify how many functions are available on open-source platform (action)
•   Make a web portal on ML Infomap server and add all those functions that are available (action)
•   How we can read the header file of any 3D image, big question that requires answer
•   If we are unable to add any function, what is the solution for that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Questions about how to build a web portal from scratch are far too broad to be answered with a small posting here, and many online resources already exist to help folks get started on big projects.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.